# Get only 2 rows from join table in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have two tables. topics & links. 
I want only two links for particular topics.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `take` to get the desired amount of records like this:

```
$topics = \App\Link::where('topic_id',$parricularTopic)->take(2)->get();
```